# proving theorem about perfect powers

Tags: algebra-precalculus, number-theory, prime-numbers, power-series

Im currently studying the journal entitled [Perfect Powers with All Equal Digits but One](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/journals/JIS/VOL8/Kihel/kihel7.pdf)

theorem: For a fixed integer $l \geq 3$, there are only
finitely many perfect $l$-th powers all whose digits are equal but
one, except for the trivial families $10^{ln}$ for $l\ge 3$ and
$8\cdot 10^{3n}$ for $l = 3$.

section{Proofs of Theorems 1}

{\sc Proof of Theorem 1.} Suppose that $l \geq 3$ is a fixed
integer. Consider a perfect $l$-th power with all identical digits
but one of them. Writing it first as
$$
x^l={\overline{a\dots aba\dots a}}_{(10)},
$$
it follows that we may also rewrite it as
\begin{equation}
\label{eq:(2)} x^l=a\frac{10^{n}-1}{9}+c10^m,
\end{equation}
where $c=b-a$. If $a=0$, we then get $x^l=b\cdot 10^m$, which
easily leads to the conclusions that $m$ is a multiple of $l$,
$b=1$ if $l \neq 3$, and $b\in \{1,8\}$ if $l = 3$.

Could you help me understand this in a simpler way? I dont understand the part where there is a +c10^m where in fact the paper uses only the diophantine equation \begin{equation}
\label{eq:(1)} a\frac{x^{n}-1}{x - 1} = y^{q}, \; \mbox{in
integers}\;~ n\geq 3,~ x \geq 2,~ 1 \leq a \leq x,~y \geq 2,~ q
\geq 2
\end{equation}

Where does +c10^m come from?
Why $b=1$ if $l \neq 3$, and $b\in \{1,8\}$ if $l = 3$?
Please help me understand this, it is more advanced than the subjects that i already took up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$a\frac{10^n-1}{9}$$

is simply the number $$aaa\cdot\cdot\cdot aaa$$ with $n$ digits $a$.

To get $\ aaa\cdot\cdot\cdot b \cdot\cdot\cdot aaa\ $ , you must add or subtract
some multiple of a power of ten.

Comment: thanks for the explanation i can understand them now  but i cant visualize this, can you help me?.Why $b=1$ if $l \neq 3$, and $b\in \{1,8\}$ if $l = 3$?

Answer (score 0):

In the point you cannot see clearly, $n$ is the number of digits of $x^l$ and $m$ is the number of digits to the right of $b$.

See at the following example explaining what happen:

$$x^l=aabaaa=aa0000+b000+aaa$$ But $$aa0000=aaaaaa-aaaa=a(111111)-a(1111)\\b000=bbbb-bbb=b(1111)-b(111)\\aaa=a(111)$$ It follows $$x^l=a(111111)-a(1111)+b(1111)-b(111)+a(111)$$
$$x^l=a(111111)+(b-a)(1111)-(b-a)(111)$$
$$x^l=a(111111)+cccc-ccc$$ $$x^l=a(111111)+c10^3=a\frac{999999}{9}+c10^3$$ Finally 
$$x^l=\color{red}{a\frac{10^6-1}{9}+c10^3}$$

Comment: thanks for the explanation i can understand them now  but i cant visualize this, can you help me?.Why $b=1$ if $l \neq 3$, and $b\in \{1,8\}$ if $l = 3$?

Comment: In the paper you can read “If $a=0$, we then get $x^l=b\cdot10^m$, which easily leads to the conclusions that $m$ is a multiple of $l$, $b=1$ if $l\ne 3$ and $b\in \{1,8\}$ if  $l=3$” so you goes to numbers of the form $b10^m$ (notice the conditional “If $a=0$”). Hence $x=\sqrt[3]{b10^m}$ so $b=1,8$ only digits that are cubes ($m$ is a multiple of $3$ has been said immediately after the conditional).

Comment: yah thanks, it really makes sense now, but correct me if i have a wrong interpretation in this. b=1,8 because they are the numbers which are perfect cubes and a single-digit number.So it cannot be 27,64 and etc because they have two digits? Is my interpretation correct? Is it right to say that it should be 1,8 because b has a range from {1.....9}? because 1 and 8 have a single digit?

Comment: Not because you must have $x^l=b\cdot 10^m$ and $b$ is a digit by hypothesis. If you consider $b$ as a two-digit integer then you change the problem and this requires another kind of solution. (excepting I misunderstand your question....).

Comment: Hi sir Piquito, Thank you for making me understand theorem number1...Can you help me with theorem number 2, where a is not equal to $0$...?I dont know what happen to every equation in this theorem,maybe it just is so advanced but even if i tried my best to undrstand this, i just cant.please help me.

Comment: I'll see this soon and I will answer. I tell you, however, that in certain papers there are often very subtle points or techniques based on high level and that's why maybe I can not understand either. I'll write you soon, I do not have time now.

Comment: Sorry dear friend. The proof uses some references and I can not see clear.No I have peace for the moment to go deep in this point. Good luck.